# Drive through large puddles now dropping oil

Tags: oil-leak

During some flooding I drove through some deep puddles (1/4 of wheel depth at most).

Now there’s a lot of water dropping from the engine block area (Mazda bongo) which contains oil.

I suspect this is just oil from the exterior of the engine rather than a leak. I’ve checked the oil level and it’s fine.

I’ll check again later.

Any thoughts? Anything I should look out for?